# Jquery Slider TypeError: $(...).getElementsByTagName is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, typeerror

This code in localhost working correctly.

```
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.ankara.gov.tr/assets/user/asset/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ankara.gov.tr/assets/user/slaythaber/js/slaythaber.js"></script>
    <!--[if IE 8]><script   src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script   src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://www.ankara.gov.tr/assets/user/slaythaber/css/slaythaber.css">

</head>

<body>
    <div id="ifocus">
        <div id="ifocus_pic">
            <div id="ifocus_piclist" style="left: 0px; top: -1140px;">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://www.ankara.gov.tr/haber/15072015-ramazan-bayrami-mesaji" target="_self"><img src="http://www.ankara.gov.tr/assets/upload/haber/resimyok.png" alt=""></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://www.ankara.gov.tr/haber/18062015-vali-kiliclar-112-acil-mekezini-ziyaret-etti" target="_self"><img src="http://www.ankara.gov.tr/assets/upload/haber/20150618-merkez4.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://www.ankara.gov.tr/haber/15062015-bisiklet-dagitimi-protokolu-imzalandi" target="_self"><img src="http://www.ankara.gov.tr/assets/upload/haber/20150615-2.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://www.ankara.gov.tr/haber/10062015-turkiye-taekwondo-federasyonu-baskani-sahin-den-vali-kiliclar-a-ziyaret" target="_self"><img src="http://www.ankara.gov.tr/assets/upload/haber/20150610-1.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://www.ankara.gov.tr/haber/10062015-ankara-buyuksehir-belediyesi-cocuk-meclisinden-vali-kiliclara-ziyaret" target="_self"><img src="http://www.ankara.gov.tr/assets/upload/haber/20150610-CX8G2822.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://www.ankara.gov.tr/haber/03062015-ankara-ya-saglik-turizmi-yatirimi" target="_self"><img src="http://www.ankara.gov.tr/assets/upload/haber/20150603-1.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="ifocus_opdiv"></div>
            <div id="ifocus_tx">
                <ul>
                    <li class="normal">RAMAZAN BAYRAMI MESAJI
                        <br>‘Bayramlar, dargınlık ve kırgınlıkların unutulduğu, toplumsal birlikteliğin pekiştiği, saygı ve ...</li>
                    <li class="normal">VALİ KILIÇLAR, 112 ACİL ÇAĞRI MERKEZİNİ ZİYARET ETTİ
                        <br>Ankara Valisi Sayın Mehmet Kılıçlar, 17.06. 2015 Çarşamba günü saat 11.00’de Ankara Valiliği 112 Acil ...</li>
                    <li class="normal">“BİSİKLET DAĞITIMI” PROTOKOLÜ İMZALANDI
                        <br>15.06.2015 Pazartesi günü saat 11.00’de Valilik Makamında, Ankara Halk Sağlığı Müdürlüğü tarafından ...</li>
                    <li class="current">TÜRKİYE TAEKWONDO FEDERASYONU BAŞKANI ŞAHİN’DEN VALİ KILIÇLAR’A ZİYARET
                        <br>Türkiye Taekwondo Federasyonu Başkanı Doç. Dr. Metin Şahin, Federasyon Disiplin Kurulu Üyesi Adnan Kurban ...</li>
                    <li class="normal">ANKARA BÜYÜKŞEHİR BELEDİYESİ ÇOCUK MECLİSİNDEN VALİ KILIÇLAR’A ZİYARET
                        <br>Ankara Büyükşehir Belediyesi Çocuk Meclisinden Meclis Başkanı ve Komisyon Başkanları çocuklar, 10.06.2015 ...</li>
                    <li class="normal">ANKARA’YA SAĞLIK TURİZMİ YATIRIMI
                        <br>Çin Halk Cumhuriyeti Sincan Uygur Özerk Bölgesi’nden bir yatırım grubunun Ankara’da gerçekleştireceği ...</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="ifocus_btn">
            <ul>
                <li class="normal">
                    <a href="http://www.ankara.gov.tr/haber/15072015-ramazan-bayrami-mesaji" target="_self"><img src="http://www.ankara.gov.tr/assets/upload/haber/thumb/resimyok.png" alt=""></a>
                </li>
                <li class="normal">
                    <a href="http://www.ankara.gov.tr/haber/18062015-vali-kiliclar-112-acil-mekezini-ziyaret-etti" target="_self"><img src="http://www.ankara.gov.tr/assets/upload/haber/thumb/20150618-merkez4.jpg" alt=""></a>
                </li>
                <li class="normal">
                    <a href="http://www.ankara.gov.tr/haber/15062015-bisiklet-dagitimi-protokolu-imzalandi" target="_self"><img src="http://www.ankara.gov.tr/assets/upload/haber/thumb/20150615-2.jpg" alt=""></a>
                </li>
                <li class="current">
                    <a href="http://www.ankara.gov.tr/haber/10062015-turkiye-taekwondo-federasyonu-baskani-sahin-den-vali-kiliclar-a-ziyaret" target="_self"><img src="http://www.ankara.gov.tr/assets/upload/haber/thumb/20150610-1.jpg" alt=""></a>
                </li>
                <li class="normal">
                    <a href="http://www.ankara.gov.tr/haber/10062015-ankara-buyuksehir-belediyesi-cocuk-meclisinden-vali-kiliclara-ziyaret" target="_self"><img src="http://www.ankara.gov.tr/assets/upload/haber/thumb/20150610-CX8G2822.jpg" alt=""></a>
                </li>
                <li class="normal">
                    <a href="http://www.ankara.gov.tr/haber/03062015-ankara-ya-saglik-turizmi-yatirimi" target="_self"><img src="http://www.ankara.gov.tr/assets/upload/haber/thumb/20150603-1.jpg" alt=""></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <a href="http://www.ankara.gov.tr/haberler" style="float: right; width:10%; margin-right:2%; margin-top:0.5%; " class="btn btn-danger">Tümü</a>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

It gives an error when I want to add my site

```
<script>
    function func1() { var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]; var script1 = document.createElement('script'); script1.type = 'text/javascript'; script1.src = 'http://www.ankara.gov.tr/assets/user/slaythaber/js/slaythaber.js'; head.appendChild(script1); } window.onload = func1;
    < /script>
        < link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.ankara.gov.tr/assets/user/asset/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
        <!--[if IE 8]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    < ![endif] -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]><script  src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    < ![endif] -->
        < link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://www.ankara.gov.tr/assets/user/slaythaber/css/slaythaber.css" />
        < script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ankara.gov.tr/assets/user/slaythaber/js/slaythaber.js">
            < /script>
                < script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js">
                    < /script>
                        < script>
                            $(document).ready(function() { jQuery('.mansetcontainer table').html(''); $('

                            <div id="ifocus" style="width: 643px;height: 395px;">
                                <div id="ifocus_pic">
                                    <div id="ifocus_piclist" style="left: 0px; top: -380px;">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="http://www.ankara.gov.tr/haber/15072015-ramazan-bayrami-mesaji" target="_self"><img src="http://www.ankara.gov.tr/assets/upload/haber/resimyok.png" alt=""></a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="http://www.ankara.gov.tr/haber/18062015-vali-kiliclar-112-acil- mekezini-ziyaret-etti" target="_self"><img src="http://www.ankara.gov.tr/assets/upload/haber/20150618-merkez4.jpg" alt=""> </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="http://www.ankara.gov.tr/haber/15062015-bisiklet-dagitimi- protokolu-imzalandi" target="_self"><img src="http://www.ankara.gov.tr/assets/upload/haber/20150615-2.jpg" alt=""></a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="http://www.ankara.gov.tr/haber/10062015-turkiye-taekwondo- federasyonu-baskani-sahin-den-vali-kiliclar-a-ziyaret" target="_self"><img src="http://www.ankara.gov.tr/assets/upload/haber/20150610-1.jpg" alt=""></a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="http://www.ankara.gov.tr/haber/10062015-ankara-buyuksehir- belediyesi-cocuk-meclisinden-vali-kiliclara-ziyaret" target="_self"><img src="http://www.ankara.gov.tr/assets/upload/haber/20150610-CX8G2822.jpg" alt=""> </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="http://www.ankara.gov.tr/haber/03062015-ankara-ya-saglik- turizmi-yatirimi" target="_self"><img src="http://www.ankara.gov.tr/assets/upload/haber/20150603-1.jpg" alt=""></a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="ifocus_opdiv"></div>
                                    <div id="ifocus_tx">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li class="normal">RAMAZAN BAYRAMI MESAJI
                                                <br>&lsquo;Bayramlar, dargınlık ve kırgınlıkların unutulduğu, toplumsal birlikteliğin pekiştiği, saygı ve ...</li>
                                            <li class="current">VALİ KILI&Ccedil;LAR, 112 ACİL &Ccedil;AĞRI MERKEZİNİ ZİYARET ETTİ
                                                <br>Ankara Valisi Sayın Mehmet Kılı&ccedil;lar, 17.06. 2015 &Ccedil;arşamba g&uuml;n&uuml; saat 11.00&rsquo;de Ankara Valiliği 112 Acil ... </li>
                                            <li class="normal">&ldquo;BİSİKLET DAĞITIMI&rdquo; PROTOKOL&Uuml; İMZALANDI
                                                <br>15.06.2015 Pazartesi g&uuml;n&uuml; saat 11.00&rsquo;de Valilik Makamında, Ankara Halk Sağlığı M&uuml;d&uuml;rl&uuml;ğ&uuml; tarafından ...</li>
                                            <li class="normal">T&Uuml;RKİYE TAEKWONDO FEDERASYONU BAŞKANI ŞAHİN&rsquo;DEN VALİ KILI&Ccedil;LAR&rsquo;A ZİYARET
                                                <br>T&uuml;rkiye Taekwondo Federasyonu Başkanı Do&ccedil;. Dr. Metin Şahin, Federasyon Disiplin Kurulu &Uuml;yesi Adnan Kurban ...</li>
                                            <li class="normal">ANKARA B&Uuml;Y&Uuml;KŞEHİR BELEDİYESİ &Ccedil;OCUK MECLİSİNDEN VALİ KILI&Ccedil;LAR&rsquo;A ZİYARET
                                                <br>Ankara B&uuml;y&uuml;kşehir Belediyesi &Ccedil;ocuk Meclisinden Meclis Başkanı ve Komisyon Başkanları &ccedil;ocuklar, 10.06.2015 ...</li>
                                            <li class="normal">ANKARA&rsquo;YA SAĞLIK TURİZMİ YATIRIMI
                                                <br>&Ccedil;in Halk Cumhuriyeti Sincan Uygur &Ouml;zerk B&ouml;lgesi&rsquo;nden bir yatırım grubunun Ankara&rsquo;da ger&ccedil;ekleştireceği ...</li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div id="ifocus_btn">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li class="normal">
                                            <a href="http://www.ankara.gov.tr/haber/15072015-ramazan-bayrami-mesaji" target="_self"><img src="http://www.ankara.gov.tr/assets/upload/haber/thumb/resimyok.png" alt=""> </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="current">
                                            <a href="http://www.ankara.gov.tr/haber/18062015- vali-kiliclar-112-acil-mekezini-ziyaret-etti" target="_self"><img src="http://www.ankara.gov.tr/assets/upload/haber/thumb/20150618-merkez4.jpg" alt=""></a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="normal">
                                            <a href="http://www.ankara.gov.tr/haber/15062015-bisiklet-dagitimi-protokolu- imzalandi" target="_self"><img src="http://www.ankara.gov.tr/assets/upload/haber/thumb/20150615-2.jpg" alt=""> </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="normal">
                                            <a href="http://www.ankara.gov.tr/haber/10062015- turkiye-taekwondo-federasyonu-baskani-sahin-den-vali-kiliclar-a-ziyaret" target="_self"><img src="http://www.ankara.gov.tr/assets/upload/haber/thumb/20150610-1.jpg" alt=""> </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="normal">
                                            <a href="http://www.ankara.gov.tr/haber/10062015- ankara-buyuksehir-belediyesi-cocuk-meclisinden-vali-kiliclara-ziyaret" target="_self"><img src="http://www.ankara.gov.tr/assets/upload/haber/thumb/20150610-CX8G2822.jpg" alt=""></a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="normal">
                                            <a href="http://www.ankara.gov.tr/haber/03062015-ankara-ya-saglik-turizmi-yatirimi" target="_self"><img src="http://www.ankara.gov.tr/assets/upload/haber/thumb/20150603-1.jpg" alt=""> </a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div><a href="http://www.ankara.gov.tr/haberler" style="float:  right; width:10%; margin-right:2%; margin-top:0.5%; " class="btn btn- danger">T&uuml;m&uuml;</a> </div>').appendTo('.mansetcontainer '); });
                            < /script>
```

Error is:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).getElementsByTagName is not a function
>   iFocusChange @ slaythaber.js:72 window.onload@ slaythaber.js:9

Comment: Edit:Before </Head> in first code  
        <head>
          <link rel="stylesheet"  href="http://www.ankara.gov.tr/assets/user/asset/css/bootstrap.min.css"   type="text/css" media="screen">
          <script   type="text/javascript"src="http://www.ankara.gov.tr/assets/user/slaythaber/js/sl      aythaber.js"></script>
       
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://www.ankara.gov.tr/assets/user/slaythaber/css/slaythaber.css">

        </head>

Answer (score 3):

`getElementsByTagName()` is a native DOM function on the `document` and other DOM element objects, not a jQuery function.

For instance, `document.getElementsByTagName("p")` works, or `$(document)[0].getElementsByTagName("p")`, but it's not a function of a jQuery object directly ... you have to access the underlying native DOM elements the jQuery query object is wrapping before you can call `getElementsByTagName()` and other native DOM query functions.  What you really want to use for the native jQuery object is something like either the `children()` or `find()` methods, both of which can take selector strings.

Comment: in that case,thisa code why in localhost working correctly?
http://i60.tinypic.com/2lut01z.png

Comment: That code segment is somehow not running on your localhost because again, that's simply not valid jQuery...

Comment: i found the problem.
i found the problem.
          <script type="text/javascript">(function(){var a=document.createElement("script");a.type="text/javascript";a.async=!0;a.src="http://img.rafomedia.com/zr/js/adrns.js?20150804";var b=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];b.parentNode.insertBefore(a,b);})();</script>

that script blocking work slider.How to remove it?

Comment: is because the script being loaded is hijacking `$` ... `function $(id){ return document.getElementById(id) }`  see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31842148/1175966