# Remove script tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<head>  
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function(){
            var a=document.createElement("script");
            a.type="text/javascript";
            a.async=!0;
            a.src="http://img.rafomedia.com/zr/js/adrns.js?20150804";
            var b=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
            b.parentNode.insertBefore(a,b);
        })();
    </script>
    <script src="js/twitter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

How to delete first script with javascript?

Comment: simple enough to remove it....but the question becomes why? Removing it won't prevent the code executing. This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: if i delete this script.this problem fixed.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31839967/jquery-slider-typeerror-getelementsbytagname-is-not-a-function/31840169#31840169

Comment: you are misunderstanding that removing it won't stop whatever is in that script from running. By the time you can remove it , the browser has already processed it. You need to outline whatever the higher level problem it creates is and explain that

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0].remove()
```

will remove the first script tag on the page.

however I advise you to elaborate as the comments suggest since it might not solve the problem you are trying to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at that script it is also using `$` alias which is conflicting with jQuery `$`  so there is a simple solution to your problem by using `jQuery.noConflict()`

As soon as you load jQuery.js in page add this tag:

```
<script>jQuery.noConflict()</script>
```

Then wrap any of your jQuery code using:

```
(function($){
  // your jQuery code

})(jQuery);
```

Or alternatively replace your ready event handlers with:

```
jQuery(document).ready($){/* your code */});
```

or

```
jQuery(function($){/* your code */ });
```

Reference : [jQuery.noConflict() docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)